# why property doc function doesn't display the help information when it is called through help(instance.attribute)

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_secret_thing = 1

    def _i_get(self):
        return self._my_secret_thing

    def _i_set(self, value):
        self._my_secret_thing = value

    def _i_delete(self):
        del self._my_secret_thing

    my_thing = property(_i_get, _i_set, _i_delete,'this document for my_thing')

instance_of = MyClass()

help(instance_of.my_thing) # not display the 'this document for my_thing'
help(instance_of)          # display the 'this document for my_thing'
```

**Question**> Why the help message for `my_thing` doesn't show up if it is called through `help(instance_of.mything)`?

Reference [python.property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you access `instance_of.my_thing`, it returns the value - and so what you are actually calling `help` on is the value `1` rather than the property.

If you access it on the class object rather than on the instance, you will get the property object, and the docstring will be attached to it; that is, use `help(MyClass.my_thing)` or `help(type(instance_of).my_thing)`.